# referencing papaparse output arrays

Tags: jquery, papaparse

I'm using papaParse to parse a CVS file. Then I want to use specific data from arrays but don't know how to reference it. I can see it in console like this:

```
Object { data: Array[15], errors: Array[0], meta: Object } index.html:42:12
```

this is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/papaparse.js"></script>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="index.css"/>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="graphbox"></div>   
    <div class="dropdownmenubox">
        <select name="CSV">
            <option value="CSV/Sheet1.csv">1</option>
            <option value="CSV/Sheet2.csv">2</option>
            <option value="CSV/Sheet3.csv">3</option>
            <option value="CSV/Sheet4.csv">4</option>
            <option value="CSV/Sheet5.csv">5</option>
            <option value="CSV/Sheet6.csv">6</option>
            <option value="CSV/Sheet7.csv">7</option>
            <option value="CSV/Sheet8.csv">8</option>
            <option value="CSV/Sheet9.csv">9</option>
            <option value="CSV/Sheet10.csv" selected="selected">10</option>
            <option value="CSV/Sheet11.csv">11</option>
            <option value="CSV/Sheet12.csv">12</option>
            <option value="CSV/Sheet13.csv">13</option>
        </select>
    </div>        
  <script>

        $( "select" ).change(function () {

          $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
          var variable = $(this).val();
          console.log(variable);
          Papa.parse(variable, {
          download: true,            
          complete: function(results) {
          console.log(results);
       }
     });
    });
  }) .change(); 

</script>

</body>
```

so let's say I want to console.log(data:Array0[5]), what would be the appropriate syntax? Thanks

Comment: results.data would be the first array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
results.data["0"][0]
```

is the correct way to access the array, solved thanks to a comment from @mplungjan